# Laravel Mass Assignment Issue seems to be inconsistent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, mass-assignment

I am working on implementing some Models in Laravel 4. When attempting to `create` a new Instance of a model, I receive a `MassAssignmentException`. From my research, I have learned that by default, all fields are considered guarded. In order to get this to work, I need to specify the `fillable` fields. Once I do that, it works fine.

However, during database seeding, I am creating some new objects using the same methods with no `fillable` attribute specified and I do not receive the `MassAssignmentException`? This is what makes no sense. Am I missing something here?

Code which threw the MassAssignmentException before I added the fillable var:

```
Role::create(array(
    'name' => 'admin'
));
```

Code in DatabaseSeeder which did not throw the Exception with no fillable var:

```
Company::create(array(
    'name' => 'ABC Toys Inc.'
));
```

Anyone know the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DatabaseSeeder class which is included in Laravel (which I assume you are using) has the Mass Assignment guarding switched off by default.

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder 
{

    public function run()
    {
        Eloquent::unguard();
    }
}
```

The Eloquent::unguard() function switches off mass assignment guarding.